# Does the SimpleSAMLphp frontend need to be on for the service provider to act like a service provider?

Tags: php, saml, simplesamlphp

Pretty simple, setup simpleSAMLphp and went through all the configuration.

The default simpleSAMLphp seems very 'open', and a little unprofessional (under reset password it says "Too Bad! Contact your university"). I know I could technically just edit out some of those messages as a theme, but does it actually need to be on at all?

Or could I simply just turn the web front end off?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are two steps, it seems, to cut down what is shown on that front page without heavily modifying the theme and core files.

Paths are relative to the home directory of simpleSAMLphp.

1. Edit the `./config/config.php` and add an `auth.adminpassword` and also set `admin.protectindexpage` to `true`
2. Edit `./dictionaries/login.definitions.json` and remove the 'university' instructions to something that is more fitting to your business.